# QuerySelector returns null from a name given in javascript array

Tags: javascript

Some similar questions did exist I admit, but all used complex naming systems that I am NOT using, or used 3rd party libraries I am not using either.

This is a straight javascript problem with simple names.

The innerHTML is not the important part. It is only included here for example of the failure.

Console log returns a value of null.

I will be using this in AFrame, not that it will work if it wont even work in javascript. My page is too big to include here anyway.

Please include js fiddle example in answers.

Please don't ask me to use xyz library, like I said, my page is already huge.

Here is my code:

```js
myArray=['there','Here','nowhere'];

var WhatPlace = document.querySelector(myArray[1]);   

console.log(WhatPlace);
WhatPlace.innerHTML = "querySelector WORKED!";
```

```html
<div id='Here'>querySelector failed!</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the unanchored fiddle, I'm on my mobile, and have no tab key, no way to press ctrl k, and only 2 types of quotes....

Comment: Please instead use a code snippet, so it will work from inside SO. Try using the `[<>]` button!

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a Hashtag in your js, at `document.querySelector(myArray[1]);` there needs to be a Hashtag to inform js to search for the id (instead of the element name)

```js
myArray=['there','Here','nowhere'];

var WhatPlace = document.querySelector("#"+myArray[1]);   

console.log(WhatPlace);
WhatPlace.innerHTML = "querySelector WORKED!";
```

```html
<div id='Here'>querySelector failed!</div>
```

Comment: _Hashtag_ . . .

Comment: A hashtag is the concatenation of `#` an a tag, you're referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)

Comment: called hashtag in german, what should i call it? hash? sharp? it should be clear what i mean

Comment: @NathanP. edit my answer if it bothers you so much :P